# Batch script executes all lines as one call

Tags: docker, batch-file

I want to automate the creation of some docker images, so I wrote a batch script. However, for some reason, the entire file is executed as one command when I run it.

I have written many batch scripts before and have never encountered this issue. Adding echo on/off doesn't change anything.

Below is the batch script I use:

```
call docker run --name mysql -e MYSQL_DATABASE=db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pwd -d mysql:latest
call docker commit mysql-sample mysql
call docker rm -f mysql-sample
```

When I execute it, I get the following:

```
call docker run --name dom-mysql-init -e MYSQL_DATABASE=ovinto_domotica -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mysql:latestcall docker commit dom-mysql-init domotics-mysqlcall docker rm -f dom-mysql-init
Unable to find image 'mysql:latestcall' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for mysql:latestcall not found.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Does anyone have experience with this, and have a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you actually using new lines to seperate the commands? And what is the actual name of your batch file?

Comment: Did you check your line-endings? Is it \r\n (dos style) or \n (linux style) ?

Comment: @XouDo, Unix/Linux-style line-breaks are no problem for DOS/Windows (at least in most situations), but Mac-style line-breaks are; but great idea anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@XouDo Thank you for your comment. It was indeed my line-ending.

For some reason, my line-ending was set to Macintosh, and I was able to convert this to Windows using Notepad++ the following way:
Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows (CR LF)